# where to position laravel config file for driver

Tags: php, laravel

i am working my way through http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/b … r-laravel/.

I have reached the following point:

```
Extending Auth
To keep our bundle entirely self contained, we’ll need to extend auth. This will allow     us to define a table just to login to our admin panel, and not interfere with the main application.
Before we create our custom driver, we'll create a configuration file, where you can     choose if you'd like to use the username or email columns from the database table.

return array(
    'username' => 'username',
    'password' => 'password',
);
```

I don't understand what to name the config file, what are its contents and where it should go in the laravel 3.2 directory structure. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bundles > bundlename > config > bundlename.php